# Bound Method - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Iloilo():
     def Population(self):
        population = 946146
        return population


class Palawan():
    def Population(self):
        population = 1104585
        return population


Iloilo = Iloilo()
Palawan = Palawan()

print(Iloilo.Population)
print(Palawan.Population)
```

I am trying to print its value but I'm getting an error saying: 
`bound method`

My question is, how can I compare both method results?

Comment: 2 errors here. When you go `Palawan = Palawan()` you are redefining the name Palawan to refer to an instance of your class instead of the class itself. This means you no longer have any way to instantiate new instances of that class. The second issue if that when you later call `Palawan.Population` because you left off the `()` you are referencing the method itself rather than calling the method and getting its output.This is when you're getting a Bound Method error. macro_controller's answer shows you how to fix both these issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do:

```
ilolio_instance = Iloilo()
palawan_instance = Palawan()
print(ilolio_instance.Population()) 
print(palawan_instance.Population())
```

Comment: Thank you so much! i kinda missed that one

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
class Iloilo():
    def Population(self):
        population = 946146
        return population

class Palawan():
    def Population(self):
        population = 1104585
        return population

a= Iloilo()
b=Palawan()
print(a.Population(),b.Population())
```